# Installing multiple versions of software with git

Tags: c++, git, installation, header, shared-libraries

I'm really struggling to understand `git`, so here's a tighter rephrasing of a previous question I had asked. I'm going to explain a hypothetical scenario, detailing what I think happens when you download some code using `git` and install it on a machine, and hopefully somebody can tell me which part I am incorrect about!

1. I run `git clone git://github.com/foo/foo.git`
2. This creates a local directory `foo`, and downloads the source code and git data
3. This source code effectively contains all the versions of the software: source files, header file, and git data for the different versions
4. I run `git checkout release-1.0`
5. This tells my system that I want to deal with version 1.0 of the software
6. I run `make`, which compiles the code for version 1.0
7. This creates a library called `libfoo.so.1`
8. I run `make install`, which installs the library
9. This copies over `libfoo.so.1` into the directory `/usr/local/lib`
10. It also copies over the header file `foo.h` into the directory `/usr/local/include`
11. This header file is the version of `foo.h` that corresponds to version 1.0 of the software
12. I now also want to install version 2 of the software, so I run `git checkout release-2.0`
13. This tells my system that I want to deal with version 2.0 of the software
14. I run `make`, which compiles the code for version 2.0
15. This creates a library called `libfoo.so.2`
16. I run `make install`, which installs the library
17. This copies over `libfoo.so.2` into the directory `/usr/local/lib`
18. It also copies over the header file `foo.h` into the directory `/usr/local/include`
19. This header file is the version of `foo.h` that corresponds to version 2.0 of the software
20. I now try to create a project which depends on version 2.0 of the software, and link it to `libfoo.so.2` which is at `/usr/local/lib`, and include `foo.h` which is at `/usr/local/include`
21. This project compiles and runs fine
22. I now try to create a project which depends on version 1.0 of the software, and link it to `libfoo.so.1` which is at `/usr/local/lib`, and include `foo.h` which is at `/usr/local/include`
23. This project does not compile ok, because `foo.h` is the header file for version 2.0 of the software, not version 1.0.

So, the thing I am puzzled about is how you can have two versions of some software installed on your machine. The actual library files `libfoo.so.1` and `libfoo.so.2` are both created and can be linked to by two different projects, but there is only one version of `foo.h` installed on the local machine. Therefore, only the version which was installed the latest will have the correct header file, because the two versions require different versions of `foo.h`.

Please can somebody explain where I am getting confused? Thanks!

Comment: You technically do have two versions of your code on your computer, but your working folder (where you cloned the repo) will only have source code corresponding to the Git branch in which you are.  So when you switch branches, you switch "software."

Comment: But what about when I run `make install`, and it copies things over from the repo folder to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`? It copes a different library file for each version, but there is only one header file. A new header file is not created for each version, unlike with the library file. But there can only exist one file name `foo.h`. So I don't understand how both versions can be linked to in a project when they require two different header files, and only one exists...

Comment: One place where there's a misunderstanding - "I run git checkout release-1.0. This tells my system that I want to deal with version 1.0 of the software". You can’t really check out a tag in Git, since they can’t be moved around. If you want to put a version of your repository in your working directory that looks like a specific tag, you can create a new branch at a specific tag with git checkout -b [branchname] [tagname]. (Found https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not actually related to git at all. You would get the same issue with anything, and the root of your problem is that by installing a version you overwrite the same files in a fixed location (`/usr/lib/foo.h`). If you want to be able to work against both versions at the same time, you have to find a way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the different versions of the library into separate directories, so that the second version to be installed will not overwrite files from the first version. Typically, you can specify an installation prefix when running the `configure` script.

For example, for version 1, you might run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/foo-v1
make
make install
```

`libfoo.so.1` will be installed in `/opt/foo-v1/lib`, and `foo.h` (for version 1) will be installed in `/opt/foo-v1/include`.

Similarly, for version 2, you might run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/foo-v2
make
make install
```

`libfoo.so.2` will be installed in `/opt/foo-v2/lib`, and `foo.h` (for version 2) will be installed in `/opt/foo-v2/include`.

Now, when you compile a program that depends on version 1 of the library, you can specify the appropriate header and library paths for version 1:

```
clang++ -I/opt/foo-v1/include -L/opt/foo-v1/lib -lfoo program1.cc
```

Similarly, for version 2:

```
clang++ -I/opt/foo-v2/include -L/opt/foo-v2/lib -lfoo program2.cc
```

Note that the exact procedure for specifying an installation prefix can vary from project to project depending on the build tools being used. Typically, there will be a `README` and / or `INSTALL` file that documents the procedure for the project in question.